# How to dodge jQuery promises completely when chaining two async jQuery functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, es6-promise

I've seen many tutorials on the new EMCA promises advocating avoidance of the "promises" in the jQuery library.  They usually say that you can dodge them by doing something like this:

```
Promise.resolve($.getJSON(url, params)); // voila!  the jQuery promise is "gone"!
```

However, this doesn't really work when I have to chain two async jQuery functions together.  How would I chain two getJSON calls (where the second call depends on the first) together without using jQuery's then() or .when()?

Instead, I only want to use Promise.all etc.

I think a similar question problem would be interleaving jquery and EMCA promises?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can adopt either of two approaches ...

**Convert then combine :**

```
var p1 = Promise.resolve($.getJSON(url_1, params_1)); // voila 1!
var p2 = Promise.resolve($.getJSON(url_2, params_2)); // voila 2!
var p3 = Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(...);
```

**Combine then convert :**

```
var p1 = $.getJSON(url_1, params_1);
var p2 = $.getJSON(url_2, params_2);
var p3 = Promise.resolve($.when(p1, p2)).then(...); // voila 1 and 2!
```

Straightforwardly, either approach will give you a native ES6 promise, `p3`, that resolves when both the jQuery promises resolve, or is rejected when either one of the promises fails.

However, you are probably interested in the results of the two `getJSON()` calls, and jQuery is awkward in this regard. jQuery's jqXHR promises pass *multiple* parameters to their success and error callbacks, whereas an ES6 promise will accept just one; the rest will
 be disregarded. Fortunately, it's fairly simple to bundle the multiple params together to make a single object. This has to be done in jQuery prior to conversion to ES6.

The "convert then combine" code expands as follows :

```
var p1 = Promise.resolve($.getJSON(url_1, params_1).then(
    function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        return { data:data, textStatus:textStatus, jqXHR:jqXHR };
    },
    function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        return { jqXHR:jqXHR, textStatus:textStatus, errorThrown:errorThrown };
    }
));
var p2 = Promise.resolve($.getJSON(url_2, params_2).then(
    function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        return { data:data, textStatus:textStatus, jqXHR:jqXHR };
    },
    function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        return { errorThrown:errorThrown, textStatus:textStatus, jqXHR:jqXHR };
    }
));
var p3 = Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(
    function(results) {
        // results[0] will be an object with properties .data, .textStatus, .jqXHR 
        // results[1] will be an object with properties .data, .textStatus, .jqXHR 
    },
    function(rejectVal) {
        // rejectVal will be an object with properties .errorThrown, .textStatus, .jqXHR
    }
);
```

The "combine then convert" approach is slightly trickier as the combined results appear (in jQuery) as an `arguments` list, which itself needs to be converted (still in jQuery) to an Array.

```
var p1 = $.getJSON(url_1, params_1).then(
    function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
        return { data:data, textStatus:textStatus, jqXHR:jqXHR }; 
    },
    function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        return { errorThrown:errorThrown, textStatus:textStatus, jqXHR:jqXHR }; 
    }
);
var p2 = $.getJSON(url_2, params_2).then(
    function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
        return { data:data, textStatus:textStatus, jqXHR:jqXHR };
    },
    function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        return { errorThrown:errorThrown, textStatus:textStatus, jqXHR:jqXHR }; 
    }
);
var p3 = Promise.resolve($.when(p1, p2).then(function() {
    return [].slice.call(arguments);// <<< convert arguments list to Array
})).then(
    function(results) { 
        // results[0] will be an object with properties .data, .textStatus, .jqXHR
        // results[1] will be an object with properties .data, .textStatus, .jqXHR
    },
    function(rejectVal) { 
        // rejectVal will be an object with properties .errorThrown, .textStatus, .jqXHR
    }
);
```

**[DEMO: resolved](http://jsfiddle.net/nb31s9oz/1/)**

**[DEMO: rejected](http://jsfiddle.net/nb31s9oz/)**

Comment: Well done! I just have to say how much I appreciate this answer. I read a couple of articles that mention casting jQuery.ajax() calls to native Promises, but none mention capturing all the parameters passed to the callback methods when ajax is done.

Comment: Thanks. With the benefit of hindsight, the folk at jQuery should have bundled the params like this from the outset. Their pioneering spirit 10 years ago has left them with some nasty little legacy issues going forward.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you! That said, in jQuery 3.0, [jQuery.Deferred is now Promises/A+ compatible](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/).

Comment: @Avraham, thanks for the compliment. Are you suggesting that Promises/A+ compatibility should change my answer?

Comment: @Roamer-1888, No need for re-write, since this is valid for previous versions and is quite useful. However, you can add an example to show that jQuery 3 works natively with Promises. Check out my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avrtau/os57p8ad/1/)

Comment: @Avraham, I don't think a 3rd example is necessary. 

jQuery 3's A+ compliance does indeed put jQuery into the A+ club but this question is all about the assimilation of jQuery promises which was always possible. 

The code in your fiddle will run under jQuery 1 and 2, as well as 3.

Answer (score 8):

JavaScript promises are [interoperable](https://promisesaplus.com/). You can mix them however you want, all proper libraries<sup>1</sup> and native promises do accept thenables<sup>2</sup> from any implementation *anywhere*<sup>3</sup>. If something foreign appears, they just will do `Promise.resolve` on it.

So usually you would write your code as if they all used the same promise implementation, and it *just works*.
However, now you want to ensure that all `.then` method calls are using your favourite implementation; or you want to use a non-standard method or feature? For that, you will have to explicitly **cast all promises** on which you are **directly invoking methods** - and nothing else.

Some examples:

```
Promise.all([$.ajax(…), $.ajax(…)]).then(…); // just works!
```

```
$.ajax(…) // a jQuery promise
.then(…)  // so this would be jQuery `then`, which we don't want.
```

```
Promise.resolve($.ajax(…)) // explicit cast
.then(function(data) {     // native `then`
    return $.ajax(…);      //   just works!
})                         // returns a native promise still
.catch(…)                  // so we can use its features
```

<sub>1: Yeah, jQuery isn't one of them until version 3.0

2: all jQuery deferreds and promises are such *thenables*, though

3: Really **everywhere** you'd expect a promise, in `Promise.resolve`, `then` callback return values, `Promise.all` arguments, …</sub>

Comment: Note that one of the _goals_ of Promises/A+ was to be compatible with jQuery promises, you can return jQuery "promises" to Promises/A+ then and it will correctly consume them. As you point out the other direction is only true from 3.0 . It might be useful to say that returning a value from a `then` chain, or passing values to an aggregation method like `.all` and so on is an _implicit `Promise.resolve`_..