# Promise of promise to simple promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

I've been playing with promises, and usually can figure out how to handle them well, but in this situation, I can't figure out how to remove one promise-wrapping level.

Here is the code:

```
let promise2 = promise1.then((nodes) => {
  return Promise.all(nodes.map(n => {

    // findConnections returns a promise
    return this.findConnections(n.get("spotifyData")); 
  }));
});
```

Now I would expect promise2 to wrap an array, but it doesn't, it wraps a promise wrapping an array. If I want to access the array, I have to do this:

```
promise2.then(level1 => level1.then(level2 => console.log(level2)));
```

level1 is a promise itself.

Of course, I could work with that, but I find the code very ugly, and I'd like to simplify it so that you can do:

```
promise2.then(level1 => console.log(level1))
```

and directly get an array there.

Any ideas ?

Thanks!

EDIT:

The findConnections() method:

```
findConnections: function (node) {
  return Ember.$.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/" + node.id + "/related-artists").then((data) => {
     return data.artists;
  });
}
```

Comment: *level1 is a promise itself.* - No, it would be an array of values. Check the example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#Examples)

Comment: Then why can't I access its content without using .then() ?

Comment: Check this [online demo](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=const%20promise1%20%3D%20Promise.resolve(%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D)%3B%0A%0Aconst%20promise2%20%3D%20promise1.then(function(nodes)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Promise.all(nodes.map(function(currentNode)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Promise.resolve(currentNode%20*%202)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D))%3B%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Apromise2.then(console.log.bind(console))%3B%0A)

Comment: Ok, then there is some other problem that I can't diagnose, because in my case, the last call to

   `promise2.then(console.log.bind(console));`

logs Promise. Any idea why ?

Comment: Try adding `console.log('processing');` right after the `promise2.then(console.log.bind(console));` line. I think you might be confusing the RE**P**L's output with the output from `console`.

Comment: I'm in a browser, I don't have a REPL, but tried anyways, I get "processing", and then the Promise being logged.

Comment: The devtools js console you're running the code in is a REPL. Are you using native Promises or some library?

Comment: I tried both with native promises and Ember's implementation (which is supposed to be compatible with the spec), no luck.

Comment: Assuming `n.get("spotifyData")` is synchronous, can you possibly show us your code for the `this.findConnections()` method?

Comment: `n.get()` is the Ember get method, and this is synchronous.
Code added for findConnections()

Comment: Which implementation are you using, what is `Promise`, and where does `promise1` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `level1` is a promise itself.

No it's not. Ember does use [RSVP](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/blob/master/README.md), which is [Promises/A+ compatible](http://promisesaplus.com/), and that means that `then` callbacks are never called with a promise (or thenable). They always receive a plain value.

Promises/A+ does mandate that there are no nested promises returned from `then`. They are always recursively unwrapped. You can just do

```
promise2.then(connections => console.log(connections));
```

If this really doesn't work, that would suggest that `promise1` is no real (or at least no standard-conformant) promise, and you should do `promise1 = Promise.resolve(promise1)` first.

Comment: You are absolutely right about adding `promise1 = Promise.resolve(promise1)` first. It's very strange, though, because promise1 is the result of a call to `Ember.$.get()` Is jQuery get not supposed to return a standard compliant promise ?

Comment: @ThomasP: jQuery? Muahahaha. Um, [no, unfortunately not](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31327725/1048572), jQuery `then` does only work with jQuery's own promises.

Comment: So it would have worked if you had wrapped the `Promise.all()` call in a `$.when(…)` :-)

Comment: Yeah, but it looks like it also works if I only wrap the original $.get() with Ember.RSVP.Promise.resolve(), which gives me a standard compliant promise, and the easy AJAX of jQuery. Pretty sad that jQuery isn't compliant, but good enough. Thanks a lot for your time!