# Promise chain continues before inner promise is resolved

Tags: javascript, promise, rsvp.js

Similar question to [Promise resolve before inner promise resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29699372/promise-resolve-before-inner-promise-resolved) but I can't get it to work nontheless.

Every time I think I understand promises, I prove myself wrong!

I have functions that are written like this

```
function getFileBinaryData () {
    var promise = new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var executorBody = {
            url: rootSite + sourceRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + fileUrl + "')/$value",
            method: "GET",
            binaryStringResponseBody: true,
            success: function (fileData) {
                resolve(fileData.body);
            },
            error: function  (argument) {

                alert("could not get file binary body")
            }            
        }
        sourceExecutor.executeAsync(executorBody);
    });
    return promise;
}

function copyFileAction (fileBinaryData) {
    var promise = new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var executorBody = {
            url: rootSite + targetWebRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + targetList + "')/Files/Add(url='" + fileName + "." + fileExt + "', overwrite=true)",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            binaryStringRequestBody: true,
            body: fileBinaryData,
            success: function (copyFileData) {
                resolve();
            },
            error: function  (sender, args) {

            }
        }
        targetExecutor.executeAsync(executorBody);    
    });
    return promise;
}
```

that I try to chain like this

```
$.getScript("/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js")
            .then(patchRequestExecutor)
            .then(function(){
                sourceExecutor = new SP.RequestExecutor(sourceFullUrl);
                targetExecutor = new SP.RequestExecutor(targetList);
            })
            .then(getFileInformation)
            .then(getFileBinaryData)
            .then(copyFileAction)
            .then(getTargetListItem)
            .then(updateTargetListItem)
            .catch(function (sender, args) {

            });
```

or like this

```
$.getScript("/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js")
            .then(patchRequestExecutor)
            .then(function(){
                sourceExecutor = new SP.RequestExecutor(sourceFullUrl);
                targetExecutor = new SP.RequestExecutor(targetList);
            })
            .then(function(){
                return getFileInformation();
            })
            .then(function(){
                return getFileBinaryData();
            })
            .then(function(binaryData){
                return copyFileAction(binaryData)
            })
            .then(function(){
                return getTargetListItem();
            })
            .then(function(listItem){
                return updateTargetListItem(listItem);
            });
```

The problem though is that even if I return new promises, the execution continues down the chain before any of the inner promises are resolved. How come? Shouldn't it wait until the asynchronous request has succeeded and `resolve()` is called in the `success` callback?

Comment: Could you please provide a smaller and complete snippet that reproduces the issue? From here I don't see any flaws in your code, should be working.

Comment: It must be the fact that not all async functions here returns a promise. I'll try to modify the code to make it happen!

Comment: Don't forget to `reject` in the error callbacks. You really should replace that `alert` for examplel

Comment: Absolutely! It was more of a debug assistant to see where it might've failed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've done nothing wrong here. This is jQuery's fault, [as so often](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23744612/1048572)<sup>1</sup>.

The problem is that jQuery is not [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) compatible (until v 3.0), and fails to adopt promises/thenable from other implementations than its own. So when your callbacks do return RSVP promises, jQuery just treats them as values to fulfill with, instead of waiting for them.
You *could* cast all of your promises to a jQuery deferred and it would work, but you really don't want that. To get the standard `Promise` behaviour (as offered by RSVP) to work, you will need to avoid jQuery's buggy `then`. This [can easily be done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31327725/1048572):

```
RSVP.Promise.resolve($.getScript("/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js"))
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    .then(patchRequestExecutor)
    .then(function(){
        sourceExecutor = new SP.RequestExecutor(sourceFullUrl);
        targetExecutor = new SP.RequestExecutor(targetList);
    })
    .then(getFileInformation)
    .then(getFileBinaryData)
    .then(copyFileAction)
    …
```

Comment: 1): This also happened [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31976947/1048572) with native promises and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31462113/1048572) with RSVP

Comment: Geebus, I never thought it could be because of that, but it does work now! Many thanks!