# How to convert a jQuery Deferred object to an ES6 Promise

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is this the correct way to convert jQuery [`Deferred`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) to a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)?

```
var p = Promise.resolve($.getJSON('api/values', null));
```

Are there any other ways to do this?

What are the limitations? I've read somewhere that jQuery deferred does not support exceptions, so I assume that a promise created out of a deferred would neither. Is this correct?

Comment: If you wrap the deferred object with a ES6 promise, I would think that it would support exceptions. The code inside a promise could be both synchronous and asynchronous.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it should, the Promise.resolve() API supports thenable as argument. So passing a jquery defer object would work just fine.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve#Resolving_thenables_and_throwing_Errors

Comment: Bear in mind that this only works if you're only interested in the first jQuery ajax parameter, i.e. if you want `.then(function (data, textStatus, jqXhr) {})` then this won't work, as `Promises` support only a single argument.  You'll need to manually convert the jQuery 'promise' into a `new Promise(...)` and marshal the arguments in there.

Answer (score 12):

I am not sure if that would work. I would recommend:

```
var p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  $.getJSON('api/values', null)
    .then(resolve, reject);
});
```

preferably you could create an adaptorfunction like:

```
var toPromise = function ($promise) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    $promise.then(resolve, reject);
  });
});

var p = toPromise($.getJSON('api/values', null));
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this and get rid of jQuery altogether. For a mobile app it'll be nice to avoid the overhead of adding jquery.min.js

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) and just use `Promise.resolve`!

Comment: @Bergi can you explain how that is relevant here (ideally give a better solution from Jquery deferred object to ES6 promise object ?

Comment: @kofifus See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31327725/1048572) and also in the OP

Comment: @Bergi I'm sorry I don't understand how this applies here

Comment: @kofifus I'm saying that the OP should use the code that he is currently using, as presented in the question, and *not* use the code suggested in this answer. This `toPromise` function makes no sense, it already exists as part of the native API: it's called `Promise.resolve`!

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer composition:

```
const successCb1 = ()=>$.getJSON('api/values'),
successCb2 = (json)=>alert(json),
errorCb = (e)=>alert(e);
Promise
   .resolve()
   .then(successCb1)
   .then(successCb2)
   .catch(errorCb);
```