# Why can't I wrap js promise resolve in a jquery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I wanted to be able to send the data from a successful jquery ajax call to other methods in my application because its quite large and it made coding sense to have one api method to work from, so I opted to try out promises. This is my first shot. I am getting some good results but clearly I am still a bit confused on context and timing.

When I run the following code, I am unable to wrap my return data from the ajax call as a jquery object without getting an error:

```
    var widgetSystem={       

       listenForClick: function(){
        $('div').on('click','a',function(){
            var $selectTarget = $(this),
                widgetid = $(this).data('widgetid');
                apiRequestData = widgetSystem.makeApiRequestForSingleWidget(widgetid);

            apiRequestData.then(function(result) {
                widgetSystem.showWidget(result);
            }).catch(function(e) {
                console.log('no way big error ' +e);
            });
        });
    },




    makeApiRequest: function(widgetid){

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "localhost",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    data: {
                       widgetId: widgetid
                    },
                    action: 'apiMethod'
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                    reject();
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    resolve(data);
                }
            });
        });
    },

    showWidget: function(data){
        $(data).appendTo('body');
        //this causes an exception in my apiRequestData.then function in listenForClick
    }

}
```

I am running un minified jquery and getting the following error in my console:

*no way big error TypeError: context is undefined*

Comment: what does it show when you write `console.log(data)` here `showWidget: function(data){...`

Comment: It gives me a nice big object in the console, exactly as I would expect!  Object { widget="<div>\r\n    <div class="p...iv>\r\n  </div>\r\n</div>\r\n"}

Comment: Not sure exactly where `context is undefined` is coming from, but I will say that this could actually be greatly simplified. `$.ajax` returns a promise itself, and both Promise results and Promise errors are pretty easy to convert into a new form (eg, you want to reduce a big JSON structure to an important identifier). `.then` returns a promise representing the return value of the function passed to `.then`, which is really handy.

Comment: did you try to invert that? `$('body').append(data);`?

Comment: I know exactly why it isn't working. I need to turn data.widget into a jquery object, not data! My API returns an object containing the html I need.

Comment: you could just access the *widget* attribute of the object and append to the body :o

Comment: @hugo, yes that is what I have done.

Comment: @charlietfl, It shows the same object I would expect it to, whether I console log it there or in the showWidget function.

Comment: did it work? like `$("body").append(data.widget)`?

Comment: @hugo - yep sure did, thanks again.

Comment: okay. that's nice. :)

Comment: There's no reason to use `new Promise` here. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31327725/1048572) for how to wrap it correctly.

Comment: "*TypeError: context is undefined*" makes no sense given the code you've shown us. Please post the part of your code that makes use of a variable called `context`.

Comment: @Bergi I can't! There is no variable in my script called context. I assume it is from the Jquery library?

Comment: @absentx: Then which line does the exception occur at? Try to log it as an object (`console.log('no way big error', e);`) and get us a stack trace, please.

Comment: @Bergi TypeError: context is undefined
 

if ( ( context.ownerDocument || context ) !== document ) {

widget.js (line 98)
widgetSystem.listenForClick/</<()widget.js (line 99)
e = Object { type="object"}

Comment: @absentx: That doesn't exactly look like jQuery, what is `widget.js`? (can you link it?)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what your HTML looks like or how the API is set up, but assuming that the API is working correctly and the data sent via POST is correct, I was able to get it working using `jsonplaceholder` api with the following code (you can find it on [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/qorowe/edit?html,js,output)).

```
var widgetSystem={       
  listenForClick: function(){
    $('div').on('click','a',function(){
      console.log('clicked');
      var $selectTarget = $(this);
      var widgetid = $(this).data('widgetid');


      widgetSystem.makeApiRequest(widgetid)
        .then(function(result) {
          widgetSystem.showWidget(result);
          return result;
        })
        .catch(function(e) {
          console.log('no way big error ' +e);
        });
    });
  },


  makeApiRequest: function(widgetid){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var root = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: root+'/posts/',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          userId:1,
          title:"Havanagila",
          body:"Testing the greatness"
        },
        success: function(xData, status){
          resolve(xData);
          //reject('whoops');
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error){
          reject(status);
        }
      });
    });
  },

  showWidget: function(data){
    $('#space').append(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(data)));
  }
}

widgetSystem.listenForClick()
```

I don't think there is an issue which how you are calling `resolve(data)` within the ajax `success` callback.  There may be an issue with the data being sent to your API such that the `error` callback is called, which in turn calls `reject` and causes the callback passed to `.catch` to be called instead of the intended callback passed to `.then`.