# Javascript: Passing variable into Promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I am working on an open source EmberJS project that is making an Ajax request for information and then needs to resolve based on a dynamic subpart of the response.

```
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const { resourceName, identificationAttributeName } = this.getProperties('resourceName', 'identificationAttributeName');
    const data         = {};
    data[resourceName] = { password };
    data[resourceName][identificationAttributeName] = identification;

    return this.makeRequest(data).then(
      (response) => run(null, resolve, response),
      (xhr) => run(null, reject, xhr.responseJSON || xhr.responseText)
    );
  });
```

....

```
makeRequest(data, options) {
  const serverTokenEndpoint = this.get('serverTokenEndpoint');
  const requestOptions = $.extend({}, {
    url:      serverTokenEndpoint,
    type:     'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data,
    beforeSend(xhr, settings) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', settings.accepts.json);
    }
  }, options || {});

  return $.ajax(requestOptions);
}
```

In the end, I need the success response to run something like

```
(response) => run(null, resolve, response[resourceName])
```

but inside the response function, I have no access to the resourceName.  How would I send this in?

here is the transpiled code:

```
  var _this = this;

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var _getProperties2 = _this.getProperties('resourceName', 'identificationAttributeName');

    var resourceName = _getProperties2.resourceName;
    var identificationAttributeName = _getProperties2.identificationAttributeName;

    var data = {};
    data[resourceName] = { password: password };
    data[resourceName][identificationAttributeName] = identification;

    return _this.makeRequest(data).then(function (response) {
      run(null, resolve, response);
    }, function (xhr) {
      return run(null, reject, xhr.responseJSON || xhr.responseText);
    });
```

Comment: What is `this` within `Promise` constructor ?

Comment: It's an Ember Object.  It holds the functions and properties

Comment: Have not tried `Ember.js` , what does `run` do ? Does `run` actually call `resolve` ?

Comment: In the lines of the question by @guest271314, I'm thinking you could do an `var _this = this` assignment, to enable access to `_this.getProperties("resourceName")` within your response. Though, know nothing about Ember either.

Comment: @cYrixmorten I tried that to no avail.  No variables are available inside the response function (except response of course).

Comment: @guest271314 yes it calls resolve with the response

Comment: Are you trying to pass `resolve` of `Promise` constructor ? Appears original `Promise` does not get fulfilled ?

Comment: @guest271314 - not at this point.  I really just want the response of the ajax request to be resolved so I can deal with it.

Comment: Does the transpiled code look much different when you use `response[resourceName]`?

Comment: @KyleMellander _"I really just want the response of the ajax request to be resolved so I can deal with it. "_ Can you create a plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate issue ?

Comment: Where is `identification` defined ?

Comment: @guest271314 - I'll work on this.

Comment: @guest271314 its just a property that is set by the user - its basically username and password being passed in.

Comment: Yes, though does not appear defined at `js` at Question ?

Comment: @guest271314 - it is defined correctly when getting to this function.

Answer (score 1):

> but inside the response function, I have no access to the `resourceName`.

Of course you do - just try it out! Arrow functions [create closures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572) as well.

Btw, you should [avoid the `Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) (and rather make `run` return something), and you should [dodge jQuery deferreds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31327725/1048572) in favour of real promises.

Comment: jQuery 3.0 is available http://blog.jquery.com/ . Have you tested that versions deferred , promise implementations to verify that _"jQuery.Deferred is now Promises/A+ compatible" is accurate ?

Comment: @guest271314: Still: 1) it's unlikely OP is already using it 2) the implementation is horrible and lacks many features 3) OP seems to want to use the native `Promise`s

Comment: @guest271314: No, I have not tested it, but I believe them. Have you tested it? Should I need to?

Comment: Would "Is "jQuery.Deferred is now Promises/A+ compatible" is accurate ?" be a good Question for SO ?

Comment: Yes, have tested it. Though probably not as thoroughly as you would; that is; what to test for ?

Comment: I'd love for your first statement to be true...but it simply isn't available inside my response function

Comment: @guest271314 I don't think so. The answer is trivial and can easily be researched. The test suite is readily available to everyone (and probably part of jQuery as well)

Comment: @KyleMellander: What exactly does "isn't available" mean? Are you getting an exception (which one)? What value do you get there when you attempt to log it (or what does your debugger say)? Are you transpiling the ES6 code (and what does the result look like)?

Comment: @Bergi - it looks like it had something to do with Bable transpiling when looking at the transpiled code, I could access the data

Comment: @KyleMellander: If the transpiled code works, then what does not work?

Comment: @Bergi - _this is available, but if I try to define it before compiling, it is not available

Comment: @KyleMellander: I thought the issue was with `resourceName`, not with `this` (or `_this`)?

Comment: @Bergi - resourceName is also available by doing this.get('resourceName') so if I have access to this, then I can grab resourceName

Comment: @KyleMellander: That should work as well, `this` will have the same value as in the excutor scope (where you use `getProperties`). But notice that calling `get('resourceName')` again is prone to race conditions, the value could have changed as the callback is asynchronous. Why not just use the `resourceName` variable, which already is in scope?

Comment: I think that I found the solution.  It looks like a closure issue with the Arrow function.  When I switched to function(response) { run(null, resolve, response[resourceName]) } everything worked as intended.

Comment: @KyleMellander: Isn't that exactly what you had in your question?

Comment: @Bergi - To be honest, I have no clue what changed.  Everything seems to be working as intended now and I don't really understand what changed

Comment: @KyleMellander: Hm, that arrow function had a return value while the `function` yields `undefined`; but that's hardly the cause.

Comment: @Bergi - with closure - are variables not scoped in unless they are used?

Comment: @KyleMellander: In effect, yes, but actually the other way round: They're (in theory) always scoped in, but optimised out (by implementations) when not used. Given that you are using `resourceName` in both versions, it doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: @Bergi - Well, I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out with this.  I've learned a lot even if I still don't fully understand why I had the issue originally.