# How can I use promises in ajax requests on mandatory data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a script that loads additional data and gives extra functionality to multiple elements of a view.
I like to take a more OPP aproach to do this so i have "classes" build for my entities. The problem i am facing right now is that the informations comes from server side so I need that data before I can give functionality.

On my script I have three Objects
User, Prospect and ProspectDetailView.

so I work in this way.

```
$(document).ready(function _document_ready() 
{

//*
ajaxStatus.showStatus('Cargando información adicional...');
var promotor        = new User();
var prospecto       = new Prospect($("input[name=record]").val());
var vistaDetalle    = new ProspectDetailView();



vistaDetalle.drawAditionalStatusTag(prospecto.data);
vistaDetalle.drawGroupDataField(prospecto.inscription);
vistaDetalle.drawInscriptionDifferences(prospecto.data, prospecto.inscription);
vistaDetalle.drawPendingRequestTag(prospecto.inscription.requests);
vistaDetalle.drawPendingTicketTag(prospecto.inscription.tickets);
vistaDetalle.drawTicketsHistoryPanel(prospecto.inscription.tickets_h);

ajaxStatus.hideStatus();
//*/ 
});//#END _document_ready()
```

As you can see create a User then a Prospect and finaly load my View Object.

Problem is that I need the data from the prospect (mandatory) before I can work with the view.

I load my Prospect like this

```
// Definiciones de la información del prospecto.
var Prospect = function (uuid){
this.uuid = uuid;

var __init__ = function (self)
{
    $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data    : {"confirm" : true },
        "context": self,
        "async" : false,
        url     : dev()+'/crmutilidades/get_inscription_data/'+self.uuid+'/'+module_sugar_grp1,
        success : function _success_get_inscription_data(response) 
        {
            this.inscription = response.data;
            this.data = response.data.prospect;
            this.paid = response.data.inscrito !== 'undefined' ? response.data.inscrito : false;
        }
    });
}
__init__(this);

}//#END Prospect
```

I need to use the async false in order to retrieve the prospect data before i can use it in the view object, and it works, but can't stop the feeling that it's a nasty hack or wrong.

So I tried to use $.when (promises i guess are called)

and did this:

```
 prospect = null;
    user = null;
    $.when(prospect = new Prospect(), user = new User).then( function(){
    view = new ProspectDetailView();
    ...Do all view calls.
});
```

Hoping that the view will execute when the prospect and user finish loading but i fail.
I get the same error .
prospecto is undefined, because everything is async.

How should I model that. As far as I can tell i need to directly pass ajax calls to the $.when method but that would defeat the purpose to have my entities separated and isolated from one another.

Comment: *"but can't stop the feeling that it's a nasty hack or wrong."* Great, because it is! the next step is to make sure that you actually have a promise to work with. $.ajax returns one, so you should present it as a property of the Prospect instance so that you can use it in a $.when.

Comment: I get you care to provide an example, i guess you mean to do a property called this.load = $.ajax({}), then explicitely do $.when(Prospect.load, user.load).then(stuff); I'll try that but i dónt like the idea of explicitely calling the load thing i though the __init__ constructor like method was better.

Comment: Your `Prospect` and `__init__` functions don't return anything, so there's no promise to await. However, they probably should not either, have a look at [Is it bad practice to have a constructor function return a Promise?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24686979/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Promise.

```
var prospect_created = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    // any necessary setup
    $.ajax({
        success: resolve,
        error: reject,
       // etc
     })
})

create_prospect.then(function(prospect){
 // create your view using the prospect
})
```

By passing resolve as the success parameter to your ajax request, whatever is returned from the ajax request will be the argument to the function you pass to the promise object's `.then` method.

Comment: `Promise`, "native" and "HTML5" have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Don't use the `Promise` constructor to create ajax promises, see [here for how to do it correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31327725/1048572)