# Unable to successfully reject chained AJAX call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise, jquery-deferred

I've got a simple JQuery event handler that is triggered when a form is submitted.

```
$('.selector').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    submitForm(status).then(updateData());
});
```

I'm trying to add the capability to cancel the second call if the first one meets a certain condition but I can't get it working. I found this question but for some reason the second function still executes when `reject()` is returned. [Rejecting A jQuery Promise In A $.ajax Success Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36889451/rejecting-a-jquery-promise-in-a-ajax-success-method).

```
function submitForm(status) {
    return $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/url/to/use",
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    }).then(function(data) {
        if (data.error === true) {
            return new $.Deferred().reject().promise();
        } else {
            // do other stuff
        }
    });
}
```

Do I need to create a deferred object and return it or is that done by just calling `then()`? I've read quite a bit about deferred and promises but still can't understand how they work.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you running?  jQuery 3.x behaves somewhat differently than 1.x/2.x.

Comment: Uh, `submitForm(status).then(updateData());` should be `submitForm(status).then(updateData);`.  Your first one ALWAYS calls `updateData()` and passes the return result as the `.then()` handler even before the promise calls the `.then()` handler.

Comment: It's JQuery 1.12.4.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to create a deferred object and return it or is that done by just calling then()? I've read quite a bit about deferred and promises but still can't understand how they work.

This is a problem with jQuery < 3 promises. In jQuery 3 the chaining issue was resolved and you can `throw` to signal an error.

Your code does not actually call `updateData` after the form is submitted as mentioned, you need to pass it a function and you're passing it a promise. A better promise library (like bluebird) or a type checker (like TypeScript) would have told you that :)

```
submitForm(status).then(updateData); // pass the function, don't invoke
```

Comment: It was calling `updateData`, the problem was I couldn't interrupt it when needed. I've changed it as you recommended but now it's not called at all.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation but I decided to get rid of `then` and just call `updateData` inside the success callback.