# Replace $.Deferred with plain JavaScript Promise

Tags: jquery, promise, ecmascript-6

I am working on a Chrome extension which has no reason to use jQuery, but which does have a reason to use the [meteor-ddp.js](https://github.com/eddflrs/meteor-ddp) script, which uses jQuery only in order to access the `$.Deferred` functionality. It only uses three methods: `reject`, `resolve` and `promise`:

```
var conn = new $.Deferred();
//...
conn.reject(err);
//...
conn.resolve(data);
//...
return conn.promise();
```

Now that JavaScript has its own native Promise objects, it seems unnecessary to include at least 69 KB of jQuery slim.min.js just to provide a promise feature.

It would be great if someone with more experience than I have of jQuery and promises could explain how the `$.Deferred` functionality works, and how it could be replaced with native Promises.

Comment: note that you will need a fallback library for some browsers  http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises

Comment: I've added a note that this project is for Chrome only

Comment: Which part do you not understand? As it stands, the question is too broad, you're asking for someone to implement deferred using Promise without giving it a try. Give it a try, and then ask a more focused question. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/

Comment: The script in your link does not require jQuery, and does not use `$.Deferred` ?

Comment: @adeneo I've corrected the link

Comment: Also have a look at [How to dodge jQuery promises completely when chaining two async jQuery functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31327725/1048572)

Comment: Do you want to shim `$.Deferred`, or do you want to rewrite the script?

Comment: @Bergi I want to shim $.Deferred

Answer (score 8):

This would be the equivalent of your code sample in es6:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // ...
  reject(err);
  // ...
  resolve(data);
});
```