# Is it safe to use await with jQuery AJAX methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, es6-promise, jquery-deferred

jQuery 3 Deferred objects are [supposed to be Promises/A+ compatible](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-and-feature-jquery-deferred-is-now-promises-a-compatible). From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286834/how-to-use-jquerys-post-method-with-async-await-and-typescript), it seems that the TypeScript compiler will yell at you for it. But this code compiles fine using the latest version of jQuery and TypeScript:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

(async () => {
    const response = await $.getJSON('https://api.github.com/');
    console.log(response);
})();
```

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await):

> If the value of the *expression* following the `await` operator is not a `Promise`, it's converted to a [resolved Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve).

I don't see an issue here considering that the expression should already be returning a Promise.

1. Does this mean it is safe to use `await` with `$.ajax` (and friends such as `getJSON`, `post`, etc.)? Or are there cases where the code will fail?
2. Why is it OK to wrap `Promise.resolve()` around a jQuery 2 Deferred object that is not Promises/A+ compliant to make it a real `Promise`, but `await`ing on a jQuery 2 Deferred object will fail?

I've referred to a TypeScript example above but I'm asking this question in the general context of JavaScript. If there are differences in how TypeScript compiler handles `await` versus how Node.js/Babel/browsers handles it in JavaScript, please elaborate in your answer.

Comment: Can't speak to when TypeScript is targeting ES5. ES2015 (aka "ES6") `await` is perfectly happy with a jQuery 2 Deferred object and works correctly with it, even though jQuery 2 Deferreds aren't Promises/A+ compatible (because `await` effectively wraps *any* thenable in an actual promise, which deals with jQuery 2 Deferred's flaw of synchronous calls to `then` callbacks when already settled).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Is this a TypeScript thing? I might be mistaken but I thought the native JavaScript `await` wasn't compatible with jQuery 2 Deferred in certain cases... maybe if `done` and/or `fail` handlers were already attached to it?

Comment: As far as I know, native `await` is fine with jQuery 2 Deferreds. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/23s1nzmt/ Naturally, if you're also using features like `done` you get their idiosyncratic behavior. As I mentioned above, one of those is that calling `then` to hook up a handler on an already-settled Deferred will call handler *synchronously*, which is a no-no in Promises/A+. But because `await` uses a native promise instead, it irons out that issue. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/8kfyhs1m/1/ But again, that's all native. If TypeScript is targeting ES5 and polyfilling, I wouldn't know if it's safe.

Comment: There might be issues with error handling. The problem is that jquery impl do not reject a promise if `onFulfill` handler throws. So you won't be able to catch this error using `try-catch` unless tsc does something really smart with the problem. Check this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/btf9ks51/)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko: Good point, another idiosyncratic behavior. If rink.attendant.6 sticks to converting to a native promise immediately (no `then` or `done` handlers on jQuery's on Deferred), he/she should be okay, but you start throwing those idiosyncratic behaviors in and it goes south fast. :-)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Feel free to add your response as an answer