# How to use await with "$.get"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

Whenever I try to run this function:

```
async function jget(url){
    await $.get(url, html => {
        return html
    })
}
```

I get an error like this:

```
(node:13924) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: #<Object>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286834/how-to-use-jquerys-post-method-with-async-await-and-typescript

Comment: @epascarello That question seems to be specific to TypeScript.

Comment: I saw that question already, I tried the solutions, but they didn't work for me.

Comment: Code there works fine with JavaScript

Comment: Why are you using jquery in node.js?

Comment: What else can I use to get a site's html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the "$.get(url, handlerFunction)" into a promise as await expects a Promise to return, so instead of your code you can write your code like below.

```
async function jget(url){
    // Note: Below variable will hold the value of the resolved promise
    let response = await fetchingData(url);
}

function fetchingData(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      $.get(url, html => {
        resolve(html)
    })
})
}
```

Comment: I had to add "return response" to jget, but it's working perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it), `jQuery.get` already returns a promise! Your approach is ignoring errors.