# Uncaught in promise error but getting result from first call

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I have two AJAX calls, the second one depends on the first one, so I decided to use promises. I keep getting **Uncaught (in promise) abc123** error in console. Note that `abc123` is the id I am expecting from the first AJAX call. The second AJAX call never goes inside success function.

```
var promise = new Promise(function(reject, resolve) {
  $.ajax({
    url: url1, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (obj1) {
      console.log("Got obj1");
      resolve(obj1.id);
    }
  });
});

promise.then((id)=> {
  $.ajax({
    url: url2, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (obj2) {
      console.log("Got obj2");
    }
  });
});
```

The structure looks exactly the same as [Basic Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). I am really confused about what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed up the order of the callback functions: `resolve` is the first argument, `reject` is the second, so you when you called the second one (`resolve(obj.id)`) you actually rejected your promise.

However, notice that [you should not use the `Promise` constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) anyway when [dodging jQuery promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31327725/1048572) - just use [`Promise.resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) to cast the jQuery promise that `$.ajax` returns to a native one:

```
var promise = Promise.resolve($.ajax({
  url: url1, 
  dataType: 'json'
})).then(obj1 => {
  console.log("Got obj1");
  return obj1.id;
});

promise.then(id => {
  return $.ajax({
//^^^^^^ don't forget this
    url: url2, 
    dataType: 'json'
  });
}).then(obj2 => {
  console.log("Got obj2");
});
```

Comment: What does dodging jQuery promises mean? And if this is the way it is done in the docs why not follow it?

Comment: @user8571142 [`$.ajax` already returns a promise](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR), but it's an instance of [jQuery's own promise implementation](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) (which [is known to have its problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23744612/1048572)) not a native `Promise`. The MDN docs never use jQuery anywhere - `new Promise` is fine for asynchronous functions that take callbacks, such as `setTimeout`.

Comment: @user8571142, if your code is in a function from which you wish to return a promise, then in all probability you need to `return promise.then(...)`, not the assigned intermediate `promise` variable.