# Use sequentially promise to run some ajax requests in Javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have steps array like:

```
var stepsToDo = [step1, step2, step3,...]
```

every step does ajax call:

```
function step1() { return $.ajax({ ... }); }
function step2() { return $.ajax({ ... }); }
```

The sample ajax call for `step 1` (`step 2` and others are similar):

```
return $.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {"step-1": ""},
            beforeSend: function () {
                writeResult("Processing-> test 1");
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    if (result instanceof Array) {
                        writeResult("Found: " + result.length + " items");
                        arr = result;
                    } else {
                        writeResult(result);
                        arr = [];
                    }
                }
            }
        });

function writeResult(str)  { console.log(str); }
```

I want to execute sequentially (defined in stepsToDo).

I tried like:

```
stepsToDo.reduce(
    (promise, method) => {
        return promise.then(method);
    },
    Promise.resolve()
);
```

Nothing happens, no print in console happens.

Why ?

Comment: `step1` etc should return a promise for the chaining to work: `{ return $.ajax...`

Comment: I put also the `return $.ajax` but not working.

Comment: The "*then will execute all ajax request in same time.*" must have been when you were missing the `return`s in the steps

Comment: What's with the global `arr` variable in your step function?

Comment: I want to be used by other steps...

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `new Promise`. Your steps are functions that return promises, not [promise executors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Creating_a_Promise) - they never would call a `resolve` callback passed into them.

Comment: you suggest to use like `return promise.then(_ => method());` ?

Comment: Yes, or even just `return promise.then(method)`

Comment: See my question updated with more info about how I do ajax

Comment: Your latest edit did remove the `method` invocation? You either need to do`.then(method)` or `.then(_ => method())`.

Comment: I put `return promise.then(method);`. I got error that `promise.then is not a function`

Comment: If you did start your `reduce` with `Promise.resolve()` as the initial value, that should not happen. Use a debugger to see what value the `promise` parameter actually holds

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164493/discussion-between-snake-eyes-and-bergi).

Answer (score 0):

For the reducer function you initially created...

```
stepsToDo.reduce((promise, method) => {
    return promise.then(_ => new Promise(method));
}, Promise.resolve());
```

...your step functions should `resolve` or `reject` the promises created in your reducer - therefore should implement the promise executor signature, I.E:

```js
type executor = (resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void;
```

For example:

```
function step1(resolve, reject) {
    $
        .ajax({ /* ... */ })
        .done(resolve)
        .fail(reject);
}
```

**EDIT**

As @Bergi states in the comments, this [is an anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). Instead you could move the Promise construction into your step functions. A basic example (the jQuery ajax API still has to be converted to promises)

```
function step1() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({ /* ... */ }).done(resolve).fail(reject);
    });
}
```

If all your steps return you promises your reducer can get much simpler:

```
stepsToDo.reduce((promise, method) => promise.then(method), Promise.resolve());
```

You could in this case even just return the result of `$.ajax`, since jQuery promises do implement a **then** method:

```
function step1() {
    return $.ajax({ /* ... */ });
}
```

If a native promise is required for error handling, i.e. `Promise.catch`, you can explicitly cast the jQuery promise to a native promise with `Promise.resolve`:

```
function step1() {
    return Promise.resolve($.ajax({ /* ... */ }));
}
```

Comment: [No, they should not. They should return promises!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)

Comment: @Bergi I updated my answer. Do you know a better approach for **$.ajax**  to **promise** API?

Comment: jQuery's `ajax` already does return (jQuery) promises - you don't need to do anything! If you want to make native promises, [just use `Promise.resolve` on them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31327725/1048572).

Comment: I think it's worth noting that jQuery promises **do not** implement `catch` afaik.

Comment: They do since v3, but yeah jQuery's [support for promise details has been below par](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23744612/1048572).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's wrong with the other answers but $.get (or ajax or post) will return a promise like.

So your step methods can look like this:

```
var stepOne = () => {
  return $.ajax({//just return the promise like
    url: "test.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {"step-1": ""}
  });
}
```

You can then reduce it to one promise that resolves with the results of the three steps:

```
[stepOne,stepTwo,stepThree].reduce(
  (p,fn)=>
    p.then(
      results=>fn().then(result=>results.concat([result]))
    ),
  $.Deferred().resolve([])
)
.then(
  results=>console.log("got results:",results),
  err=>console.warn("Something went wrong:",err)
);
```

You see I don't pass `Promise.resolve` as second argument to reduce but `$.Deferred().resolve([])`, this is jQuery promise like value. You can now support browsers that don't have native promises without the need to polyfill.

Although if you need to support those I'd recomment not using the arrow function syntax and use `function(something){return something}` instead of `something=>something`

Answer (score 0):

There most be something missing from the original question or the implementation. If all the step functions return the`$.ajax` promise then the `Array.reduce` pattern should work.

Below is a working prove of concept using a `step()` function to simulate the asynchronous code execution and using the exact same `Array.reduce` pattern:

```js
// Step generator
function step(number) {
  return function() {
    return $.Deferred(function(def) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('Running Step ', number);
        def.resolve();
      }, Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(250)));
    }).promise();
  }
}

// List of steps
var stepsToDo = [step(1), step(2), step(3), step(4), step(5)];

// Consume steps one at a time
stepsToDo.reduce(
  (promise, method) => {
    return promise.then(method);
  },
  Promise.resolve()
).then(() => console.log('All Done!'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: And how can I stop at specific `step` the exceution ?

Comment: @SnakeEyes That is a different question. If the promise of any `step` is rejected it will break the chain and stop other steps from executing. In your case if any ajax request returns a none `2xx` http response, jQuery will reject the promise automatically.