# JavaScript Promise .then() and .catch firing at the same time

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am turning my comments on wordpress into an ajax driven system.

All is good so far, until I bumped into an issue with the .catch() method firing straight after the .then() method.

Here is my code...

Ajax engine

```
commentAPI: function(action, encoded, userID) {
    let self = this;

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
       //console.log("ajax call to " + self.ajaxURL + " with action " + action);

        jQuery.ajax({               
            url: self.ajaxURL,
            type: 'post',
            data: 'action='+action+'&data='+encoded,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data, code, jqXHR) { resolve(data); },
            fail: function(jqXHR, status, err) { console.log('ajax error = ' + err ); reject(err); },
            beforeSend: function() {} //display loading gif
        });
    });
},
```

The method handling the comment form submission

```
handleReplyFormSubmit: function(form) {
    let self = this;

    this.removeErrorHtml(form);

    // Serialize form to name=value string
    const formdata = jQuery(form).serialize();

    // Validate inputs
    // * Wordpress doing this for now and providing error resonse 

    // Encoode data for easy sending
    const encodedJSON = btoa( formdata );

    this.commentAPI('dt_submitAjaxComment', encodedJSON).then(function(response){
        console.log('firing then');

        if( response.error == true ) {
            self.printFormError(form, response.errorMsg);
        }

        else { 
            let html = response.commentHTML;
            console.log('html returned' + html)
            jQuery(form).append(html);
            Jquery(form).remove();
        }

    }).catch(function(err) {            
        console.log('firing catch');

        if( err !== undefined && err.length > 0 ) { 
            self.printFormError(form, err);
        }

        else { 
            self.printFormError(form, 'Unkown error');
        }
    });

    return false;
},
```

The code is doing what it is supposed to, but the catch method is being fired too, which is making error handling frustrating...

[image: Output of code. Notice the console.log('firing catch') is being fired]

Notice how this is being fired

```
console.log('firing catch')
```

But this isn't ( within the ajax fail function )

```
console.log('ajax error = ' + err );
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Promises

It is common that a `then` fires, and then a later `catch`: it means that some error was encountered in your `then` handler code, so the `catch` fires. `Catch` handlers will fire:

- If there is an error in the asynchronous operation, so the Promise is rejected.
- If there is an error in any previous `then` handler.

So, the following code:

```
Promise.resolve()
.then( () => {
  console.log('this will be called');
  throw new Error('bum');
  console.log('this wont be logged');
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log('this will be logged too');
  console.log(err); // bum related error
});
```

Will yield logs both from `then` and `catch` handlers.

### Your code

Inside your `then` handler there is this code:

```
    else { 
        let html = response.commentHTML;
        console.log('html returned' + html)
        jQuery(form).append(html);
        Jquery(form).remove();
    }
```

Notice how the last line have `Jquery` instead of `jQuery`, which is a typo. I bet this is the error causing the `catch` to fire.

### On top of that

Modern verions of jQuery just return a promise from `$.ajax()`, so there is no need to wrap it into another promise.

This code:

```
commentAPI: function(action, encoded, userID) {
  let self = this;

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  //console.log("ajax call to " + self.ajaxURL + " with action " + action);

    jQuery.ajax({               
        url: self.ajaxURL,
        type: 'post',
        data: 'action='+action+'&data='+encoded,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, code, jqXHR) { resolve(data); },
        fail: function(jqXHR, status, err) { console.log('ajax error = ' + err ); reject(err); },
        beforeSend: function() {} //display loading gif
    });
  });
},
```

Should just be:

```
commentAPI: function(action, encoded, userID) {
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: this.ajaxURL,
        type: 'post',
        data: 'action='+action+'&data='+encoded,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {} //display loading gif
    });
},
```

So you can handle success and failure in `commentApi` `then` and `catch` handlers, instead of passing `success` and `fail` callbacks to resolve or reject a wrapping Promise.

### The ajax success params

The `success` callback param takes three parameters. However, Promises **usually** just take one.

**But**, jQuery does pass the same three arguments to the `then` handler, so  in case you need access to them, you can still use them in the handler:

```
this.commentAPI('dt_submitAjaxComment', encodedJSON).then(function(data, code, jqXhr){
 // the three arguments will be accessible here.
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did see the typo before your response, but it did fix it. Why was the error just 'undefined'? Should I check for another type of error object in the catch also?

Comment: Also when reducing the commentAPI as you suggested, what params are passed to the promise resolve/reject callbacks? Same as the default which I've listed in my ajax function?

Comment: "Could just be" should read "Should just be" to avoid the [explicit promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: You don't need to pass params, you call `then` and `catch` right after the ajax call. I'll update my answer later with an example.

Comment: You might want to [use `Promise.resolve(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31327725/1048572), though