# How to implement Promise's then in async/await?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, promise, async-await

I have a following `async/await` method:

```
async todo() {
    const res = await axios.get('/todo')
}

getTodo() {
    this.todo()
}
```

Now, in `async/await`, how do you know that request is completed (200)? In Promises, we simply use `then`:

```
// store/todo.js
todo() {
    const res = axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/todo'
    })
    return res
}

// components/Todo.vue
getTodo() {
    this.todo().then(res => {
        console.log('Request Executed Successfully!')
    })
}
```

This works perfectly but when I try to add `async/await` in getTodo and execute something like this:

```
async todo() {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get('/todo')
      return res
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
}

async getTodo() {
  try {
    await this.todo()
    console.log('Request Completed')
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jfn483ae/

It just doesn't work. The log gets executed before the request is completed i.e. after some error has occured. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: "The log gets executed before the request is completed. " — No, that won't happen.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/ropuwejomo/1/edit?html,js,console — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added a Vue Demo! Please check. There's error but still logs the result.

Comment: @Quentin You can add a wrong URL in your code too! You still get the log.

Comment: @Sanjay — When you said "how do you know that request is completed?" did you mean to ask "How can you tell the difference between a request completing and an exception being thrown?"

Comment: @Quentin Yes, exactly! And sorry for the incomplete posting.

Comment: In the main function where the async request is performed, I can catch the error but in other function it doesn't actually work.

Comment: In the code in the question you don't try to catch it, in the code in beyond the link, you catch it in `getTodo`. The exception won't show up in the calling function because you **already** caught it.

Comment: @Quentin That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if it makes sense to label this as duplicate, but this other answer surely will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51686223/javascript-promise-then-and-catch-firing-at-the-same-time/51686398#51686398

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The log gets executed […] after some error has occured.

Yes, in your new `todo` method you `catch` the error and then return `undefined` as a normal result. Just don't use `try`/`catch` when you cannot handle the error, use the same code as you did orignally and the promise will work the same when you `await` it:

```
todo() {
  return axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/todo'
  })
}
async getTodo() {
  try {
    await this.todo()
    console.log('Request Completed')
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems a better way to do! Thanks!