# Promise.all then callback executed only one time

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have this code part, loading 3 AJAX requests and generate charts:

```
class IncidentStats {
  constructor($statsForm) {
    this.$statsForm = $statsForm;
    this.charts = [];

    this.$statsForm.on('submit', event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.renderCharts();
    });
  }

  prepareFormData(key) {
    const formData = this.$statsForm.serializeArray();

    formData.push({
      name: 'key',
      value: key,
    });

    return formData;
  }

  renderCharts() {
    Promise.all([
      this.renderGeneralStats(),
      this.renderServiceRepartitionStats(),
      this.renderServerRepartitionStats(),
    ]).then(() => console.log('TEST'));
  }

  // The two other methods does nearly the same thing.
  renderServiceRepartitionStats() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      $.post(this.$statsForm.attr('action'), this.prepareFormData('serviceRepartition'), data => {
        this.charts['incident-service-repartition-stats'] = this.createTop10Chart(
          $('#incident-service-repartition-stats'),
          'Alertes Nagios',
          data
        );
        resolve();
      }, 'json');
    });
  }
}
```

I use promise in order to do some stuff at the very end of the 3 charts loading, but want to keep the loading sync.

The `console.log('TEST')` on the `then` callback works at the first loading.

On second form submit, the charts are indeed reloaded but the `then` callback is never called.

I'm sure I'm missing something, but what? :-)

Thanks

Comment: you miss [mcve].

Comment: add a catch block to Promise.all and check if it is getting triggered.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31327725/1048572.

Comment: @appleapple how would you like me to give a complete and verifiable example? without modify all the code (internal HTTP calls).

Comment: @Soullivaneuh how would you like me to give an answer if I cannot run it at all? I don't even know whether your ajax works.

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure `$.post` would return a native `Promise`. So it's probably fine here.

Comment: @appleapple Not a native one, but that's still no reason to use the antipattern (with the mistake of not handling errors anywhere). See the second link I posted.

Comment: @Bergi can you `await` on non native `Promise` (and get the result value)? (I always use native one so I don't need to check.)

Comment: @appleapple Yes you can. But if you want to be sure, just use `Promise.resolve(…)` on the non-native one.

Comment: @Bergi happy to know that. But I think I'm not convinced yet to use non-native `Promise`. Would look for more resource. thanks anyway.

Comment: @appleapple Well if you want to use `$.ajax` you *have* to use a non-native promise implementation...

Comment: Using jQuery promise did solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found the solution. Just do not create a new Promise when you are using jQuery ajax call. Just returns the call works because it's also a promise:

```
renderServiceRepartitionStats() {
  return $.post(this.$statsForm.attr('action'), this.prepareFormData('serviceRepartition'), data => {
    this.charts['incident-service-repartition-stats'] = this.createTop10Chart(
      $('#incident-service-repartition-stats'),
      'Alertes Nagios',
      data
    );
  }, 'json');
}
```

I understand using `new Promise` is overkill here, but I don't know why this was causing my issue... Maybe someone can add some details here.