# How can I achieve Promise.all().then() behavior with jQuery.when().done() if I have an unknown number of requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have a little code segment like this:

```
var requestArray = [];
thingArray.forEach(function (thing) {
    var uri = "https://server/_api/endpoint/things(" + thing.Id + ")";
    requestArray.push($.ajax({
        url: uri,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose'
        }
    }));
});
$.when(requestArray).done(function(responseArray) {
    responseArray.forEach(function(response) {
        // response.responseJSON is undefined
    });
});
```

and I realized I'm having the timing issue and `responseJSON` is undefined because I'm passing an *array* of Deferreds to `$.when()`, expecting it to be like `Promise.all()` (which does take an array), but `$.when()` just takes an unstructured "group" of Deferreds, so in my case `$.when().done()` is resolving instantly because of the Array object passed in.

I tried to hack my way around it by doing

```
$.when(requestArray.forEach(function(req){ return req; })).done(function(responseArray) { })
```

(can't destructure like `...requestArray` because IE 11), but in that case `responseArray` ends up being `undefined`.

Looking back over the [documentation for `$.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/), I see that all the examples have a known number of requests, and therefore can set up the `done` function with a known number of parameters, like

```
$.when(req1, req2).done(function(resp1, resp2) { // etc })
```

So, how can I set up `$.when().done()` to work if I have an unknown number of requests?  My `thingArray` in the example above is the result of a previous query, and could have any number of elements.

Comment: Don't. Just [use real promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31327725/1048572).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Function.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to invoke a function with an array as a list of parameters. To get the responses, iterate the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) array like object:

```
$.when.apply($, requestArray).done(function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        console.log(arguments[i]);
    }
});
```

**Demo**:

```js
var d1 = $.Deferred();
var d2 = $.Deferred();
var promiseArray = [d1.promise(), d2.promise()];

$.when.apply($, promiseArray).done(function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log(arguments[i]);
  }
});

d1.resolve("Fish");
d2.resolve("Pizza");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But again, you are setting up the example with a known number of requests, so then you set up your `done` function with a _known_ number of parameters.  I will not know the number of parameters to define in the `done` function because I don't know the number of responses I'm expecting.

Comment: The `.done()` problem can be easily solved with `arguments`. See updated answer.

Comment: That's starting to get there, but still a bit problematic, because if there is one request (and one response), there will be three arguments, `data`, `textStatus` and `jqXHR`.  But, if there are more than one request (and more than one response), each argument will be an array with the array containing the `[data, textStatus, jqXHR]`.  Is there any way to get more consistent behavior?  Checking every time to see if the first argument is an object or an array and then having branching logic from there seems inefficient.

Comment: You'll get an array of arrays back. Have you tested it?

Comment: I have, and with one request I don't get a single array with the three things (making the argument count one), I get the `data`, `textStatus` and `jqXHR` as separate arguments, not grouped in an array, making the argument count three. For multiple requests/responses I get the array of arrays.

Comment: This means that you'll need to check the length of the `requestArray` in the `.done()` block. If the length is 1, all arguments are part of a single request.