# Why am I catching a rejected Promise in a try/catch instead of the Error the Promise was rejected with?

Tags: javascript, promise, try-catch, es6-promise, catch-block

Javascript in a webbrowser.

There is an `async` event handler. Inside this event handler a `try/catch` is used. Inside the `try` block an asynchoronous functions is called synchronously with `await`.

Inside the `catch` block the caught data should be processed. But instead of the error, it catches a rejected Promise with `PromiseState: 'fullfilled'` and the error it was rejected with as `PromiseResult`.

Code:

```js
try {
    $(document).ready( async function handleEvent( event ) {
        try {
            //async function called synchronously
            await doSomethingAsync( event );
        } catch( xcp ) {
            //xcp is of type Promise
            //console output shows that it is a Promise with PromiseState: 'fullfilled'
            //and the Error as `PromiseResult`
            console.error( xcp );
        }
    });
} catch( xcp ) {
    console.error( xcp );
}

async function processAjaxError ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
    let error = new Error ( "textStatus: "+textStatus+", errorThrown: "+errorThrown );
    return error;
}

async function doSomethingAsync( event ) {
    //using a Promise as return type
    return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {
        let ServerCall = {
            url: "example.com",
            type: "POST",
            data: {},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
                //success -> let the promise resolve
                resolve( data, textStatus, jqXHR );
            },
            error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                //failure -> let the promise reject
                let error = processAjaxError( ...arguments );
                reject( error );
            },
        }
        $.ajax( ServerCall );
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Why am I catching the rejected Promise instead of the Error the Promise was rejected with?

Comment: Can you post your `doSomethingAsync`? I would strongly suggest investigating your side note 1. It is atypical to need to `catch` anything other than an Error, and even more so when using `await` to have to catch a Promise that keeps its Error in its non-error resolution value. Your code reads more like you would see `return Promise.resolve(new Error())` somewhere in your `doSomethingAsync`.

Comment: try { ... } catch(error) {...} can't catch rejected promises except await them. Read this very nice article:  https://dmitripavlutin.com/return-await-promise-javascript/

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I added the condensed code of `doSomethingAsync` to provide more context. It returns a `Promise`, it uses jQuery `ajax` and resolves or rejects the promise depending on if the `success` or the `error` handler of jQuery `ajax` was called.

Comment: "*there is a check if a `Promise` was caught*" - that does not make sense. One does not throw promises, one throws errors.

Comment: Btw, [never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572), and [don't pass callbacks to `$.ajax` but use the returned promise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31327725/1048572)!

Comment: Since the problem seems to be what I return from the async function, I changed subject and content of the question.

Comment: `reject( error );` will not reject the promise with a fulfilled promise. Please show us the rest of the code. Do you use `throw` or call `reject()` anywhere else?

Comment: I added a code example for a complete html page, which reproduces the problem. My legacy code is magnitudes more spaghetti. But this is a condensed working example.

Comment: The problem - now that you moved `let error = new Error( "Ajax call failed" );` into `let error = processAjaxError( ...arguments );` is that `processAjaxError` is an `async` function which always returns a promise, which is inappropriate here. Remove the "`async`" and it'll throw the error as expected.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a bunch! Do you want to answer the question?