# How do I make jQuery wait for an Ajax call after success

Tags: asp.net-mvc

> I have created modal pop up to upload document.  If its successfully
>   upload then I added $("#success-alert") for display meassage but
>   modalpop close immediately
>
> I want the user can easily read message.

```
var Urldata = "../controllerName/functionname";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: Urldata,
    data: fd,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (response) {

        //for display message on DocsModal
        $("#success-alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
            $("#success-alert").slideUp(500);
        });

        //I want wait for 10 sec for read meassage

        //this will close DocsModal
        $('#DocsModal .close').trigger('click');
        $("#DocsModal").modal('hide');


    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to await the ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612372/how-to-await-the-ajax-request)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.setTimeout()` function to wait for 10 seconds before hiding the modal, see this example below:

```
// number in milliseconds, 10 seconds mean 10000
window.setTimeout(function() {
    $('#DocsModal .close').trigger('click');
    $("#DocsModal").modal('hide');
}, 10000);
```

Reference: [`window.setTimeout()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)